# Xbox 360 Riften Merchant Chests

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

How do I restock the merchant chests in Riften? I've tried just waiting 48 hours and that didn't work

Answer (score -1):

Save first, kill the merchant(s) then load the save and talk to them. Good luck!

Comment: But who are the merchants?

Comment: The merchant is the person to whom the chest belongs to. For example look up the Dawnstar secret chest if you don't know about it already. You would kill Ahkari to restock this chest. If you don't know the merchant, find the one closest to the chest and kill him/her. Keep trying this until you find the exact merchant. Remember to save first, kill, and reload the save. This works if waiting doesn't. Good luck!

Comment: Well Ik that! But who specifically?